# Cmake does not rebuild dependent after prerequisite changes

Tags: cmake, dependencies, rules

I have the following dependency diagram

```
a.txt <- prereq <- stamp <- dest
```

where `prereq` and `dest` are targets, and `a.txt` and `stamp` are files. I want stamp to be updated whenever `a.txt` changes.

To achieve that, I have the following CMakeLists.txt file:

```
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
 project(sample)

 # variable holding location of stamp and a.txt file
 set(STAMP ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/stamp)
 set(ATXT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/a.txt)

 add_custom_target(
         prereq
         DEPENDS ${ATXT}
 )


 add_custom_command(
         OUTPUT ${STAMP}
         COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "Update stamp."
         COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${STAMP}
         DEPENDS prereq
 )

 add_custom_target(dest ALL DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/stamp)
```

Initially, I have the following files

```
$ ls
a.txt
CMakeLists.txt
```

After running cmake and make for the first time we get the expected behavior,

```
$ cmake .
$  make
[  0%] Built target prereq
[100%] Generating stamp
Update stamp.
[100%] Built target dest
```

However, after touching `a.txt`, I would expect `stamp` to get updated, but it does not.

```
$ touch a.txt
$ make
[  0%] Built target prereq
[100%] Built target dest
```

Is this a bug in cmake or is this the expected behavior? How can we force cmake to run the touch command every time `prereq` changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DEPENDS` in `add_custom_target()` and `add_custom_command()` calls are behaving differently.

Just move `ATXT` as dependency of your `add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${STAMP} ...)` call should solve the problem, because naming non-output files in `add_custom_target()` won't work.

See [`add_custom_command()` documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html):

> `DEPENDS`: Specify files on which the command depends. If any dependency is an `OUTPUT` of another custom command in the same directory (`CMakeLists.txt` file) CMake automatically brings the other custom command into the target in which this command is built. If `DEPENDS` is not specified the command will run whenever the OUTPUT is missing.

See [`add_custom_target()` documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html):

> `DEPENDS`: Reference files and outputs of custom commands created with `add_custom_command()` command calls in the same directory (`CMakeLists.txt` file).

The `DEPENDS` parameter in `add_custom_target()` is only meant to determine target/custom call dependencies.

**Edit: Alternatives for "Late Dependency Injection"**

1. If you are in the same `CMakeLists.txt` file you can `APPEND` dependencies to a previous custom command `OUTPUT`:

   ```
   add_custom_command(
       OUTPUT ${STAMP}
       COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "Update stamp."
       COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${STAMP}
   )

   add_custom_target(dest ALL DEPENDS ${STAMP})

   add_custom_command(
       OUTPUT ${STAMP}
       DEPENDS ${ATXT}
       APPEND
   )
   ```
2. You can add some dummy output to have a custom command for your `prereq` target, but to retrigger the build of `dest` you need to touch some of the inputs or remove the output of `dest` (`add_dependencies()` itself does not re-trigger a custom target, it just makes sure one is called before the other):

   ```
   add_custom_command(
       OUTPUT ATxtCheck
       COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E remove ${STAMP}
       COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ATxtCheck
       DEPENDS ${ATXT}
   )

   add_custom_target(prereq DEPENDS ATxtCheck)

   add_custom_command(
       OUTPUT ${STAMP}
       COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "Update stamp."
       COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${STAMP}
       DEPENDS prereq
   )

   add_custom_target(dest ALL DEPENDS ${STAMP})
   ```

**References**

- [Why does CMake make a distinction between a "target" and a "command"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11971917/why-does-cmake-make-a-distinction-between-a-target-and-a-command)
- [cmake: struggling with add_custom_command dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010212/cmake-struggling-with-add-custom-command-dependencies)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Indeed what you suggest works, but the reason why I structured the cmake this way in the first place was because I wanted to dynamically add dependencies by using  the `add_dependencies` command, and that only works on `targets` and not `output files`. If I use the `DEPENDS` command in `add_custom_command`, then I will not be able to use that command and will have to specify the dependencies explicitly.

Comment: @dzhelil You're welcome. You can always add a custom target for grouping or dependency injection, you just would have to move the source file dependencies in an additional custom command. I will update my answer accordingly tomorrow.